# GVIM: How to pass in multiple arguments via a file under windows

Tags: windows, vim

Is anyone aware of a command line option or a way to pass in a file to gvim which will use the contents of that file as a list of arguments?

Achieving this without having to populate argv with a list of files.

The problem is that vim is a unix tool which by default assumes that a list of files would be piped in, if there are say 1000 files that need to be opened, however in the windows world there is a limit to how many arguments you can have on the command line. The way to do this on a windows command line is to have a file which contains all the arguments you wish to pass onto the program. I am wondering if [gvim](http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc) provides such an option.

Note: This is to invoke gvim in a windows compatible way i.e. avoid using extremely long argument lists

Comment: same as `vim $(cat file)` on linux box...

Comment: I think that still uses vims argv which is what I am trying to avoid

Comment: What's the goal? Open a lot of files at once (wildcards might help to shorten the list), or execute certain vim commands?

Comment: open alot of files at once without consuming argv

Comment: @Har what is the problems with the files being in argv? You can access them using the argv() function

Comment: windows has a very small upper limit of this and I am using windows to try to open alot of files in one command line i.e. gvim file1 ..... file1000000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution:

1. list your files in `files`,

   ```
   file1
   file2
   file3
   ```
2. open Vim with the command below,

   ```
   $ vim -c next `cat files`
   ```

Comment: I get this when I do it: Error detected while processing command line:
E492: Not an editor command: file1

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally a word.