# Linux cat command output with new lines to be read using vim

Tags: linux, vim, cat

I am trying to open all the files listed in file `a.lst`:

```
symptom1.log
symptom2.log
symptom3.log
symptom4.log
```

But trying the following command:

```
cat a.lst | tr "\n" " " | vim -
```

opens only the stdin output

```
symptom1.log symptom2.log symptom3.log symptom4.log
```

It doesn't open `symptom1.log, symptom2.log, symptom3.log & symptom4.log` in vim.

How to open all the files listed in a.lst using vim?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32333439/546861) is another solution to the same problem that will work on any system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use xargs to line upp the arguments to vi:

`vim $(cat 1.t | xargs)`

or

`cat a.lst | xargs vim`

If you want them open in split view, use -o (horizontal) or -O (vertical):

```
cat a.lst | xargs vim -o
cat a.lst | xargs vim -O
```

Comment: Thank you it worked along with `cat a.lst | tr "\n" " " | xargs vim` option. Special thanks for the extra options.

Answer (score 2):

`while read f ; do cat $f ; done < a.lst  | vim -`

Comment: Thank you for the alternate method

Answer (score 2):

I like a variation on Qiau's xargs option:

```
xargs vim < a.lst
```

This works because the input redirection is applied to the `xargs` command rather than `vim`.

If your shell is bash, another option is this:

```
vim $(<a.lst)
```

This works because within the `$(...)`, input redirection without a command simply prints the results of the input, hence expanding the file into a list of files for vim to open.

**UPDATE**:

You mentioned in comments that you are using `csh` as your shell.  So another option for you might be:

```
vim `cat a.lst`
```

This should work in POSIX shells as well, but I should point out that backquotes are deprecated in some other shells (notably bash) in favour of the `$(...)` alternative.

Note that redirection can happen in multiple places on your command line. This should also work in both csh and bash:

```
< a.lst xargs vim
```

vim may complain that its input is not coming from a terminal, but it appears to work for me anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the simplified solution, i am using csh